# Mini weather station project not working

Tags: networking, sensors, esp8266, arduino, microsoft-windows-iot

I have been trying to do this project for 2 weeks. The project is about mini weather station. It uses esp8266, DHT11 sensor,BMP180 sensor and FC 37 rain sensor. I have taken reference from the following website.**https://how2electronics.com/iot-live-weather-station-monitoring-using-nodemcu-esp8266/**

I am not able to paste the code. that is why I am attaching the link. My problem is that, the serial monitor is stopping at the point where it generates the IP address and on checking the IP address, I am getting "site cannot be reached".

I also tried changing the baud rate to 9600 in my monitor and code as well and still doesn't work.

Comment: you pasted the link ... you could have pasted the code

Comment: The normal rules for troubleshooting applies here, Have you checked that all parts is working, have you followed the instructions by the letter? And to do that you need to write or use example code for the different steps.

Comment: @DharshiniiRavikumar, the last line demanding that someone help you is very rude

Comment: Also without seeing your code, we can't tell what errors you introduced when you copied it from the website.

Comment: Make sure your router isn't in "AP isolation" mode. (Sometimes called "client isolation") it will stop two devices communicating via wireless.

Comment: Please paste your actual code?